# Module "QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard" not found with In Qt5 with widget application on Windows

Tags: qt, qt5

I want to use QT5's virtual keyboard in my application. My code is as below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
    ...
}
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't work. When I move the qlineedit's input, it shows that "qrc:/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/content/InputPanel.qml:33:1: module "QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard" is not installed"

Comment: Have you installed the qtvirtualkeyboard module? If you haven't, then run the Qt maintenance tool and install that module

Comment: I can find it in "plugin" folder, so it should be installed.  Is there any other settings need to be set?

Comment: Have you installed that module? Please give comments that correlate with my comments otherwise my comments do not make sense

Comment: the module has installed